# Working with structured object arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, I have an array of (x, y) points of the following structure:

```
arr = np.array([([1.     ], [2.     ]),
                ([1., 93.], [5., 46.]),
                ([4.     ], [3.     ])],
               dtype=[('x','O'), ('y', 'O')])
```

i.e. these points are grouped into such innermost arrays. The size of the innermost array might by arbitrary, but it's always same for x and y.

I want to be able to perform two things:

a) Expand the innermost arrays by concatenating their content, so for the above example the result looks like:

```
np.array([( 1.,  2.),
          ( 1.,  5.),
          (93., 46.),
          ( 4.,  3.)],
         dtype=[('x','f8'), ('y','f8')])
```

b) For each (outermost) entry select element with, say, largest y:

```
np.array([( 1.,  2.),
          (93., 46.),
          ( 4.,  3.)],
         dtype=[('x','f8'), ('y','f8')])
```

I believe there should be a way of doing this efficiently without using ugly for loops. Would appreciate any help.

**UPD ( a and b using ugly loops ):**

(arr is the array defined in the beginning of the post)

a)

```
np.array([(x_, y_) for x, y in arr for x_, y_ in zip(x, y)], dtype=[('x','f8'), ('y','f8')])
```

b)

```
np.array([(x[np.argmax(np.array(y))], y[np.argmax(np.array(y))]) for x, y in arr],dtype=[('x','f8'), ('y','f8')])
```

Problem is also that in reality I have not just two fields (x and y), but 77 fields of various types (floats, integers, booleans)... So these expressions will grow to many lines.

Comment: Once you place Python lists into a NumPy array (resulting in an `object` dtype) you are forced to use Python loops to iterate over the items in the lists.

Comment: Show us how you'd do this with ugly loops.

Comment: @hpaulj updated the post

Comment: @unutbu would it make a change if they are not Python lists but NumPy arrays by themselves (still stored under `object` dtype)?

Comment: @SiLiKhon: For best performance with NumPy you want your data in a **single** big array of native dtype (not `object`). Only when the data is in one contiguous block of memory can NumPy leverage the dtype and shape of the data to perform fast vectorized operations. When you have a NumPy array of `object` dtype holding NumPy arrays, each subarray is in its own possibly discontiguous block of memory. NumPy can no longer perform any fast vectorized operation over the subarrays. It is done with essentially a Python loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), you could store your data in a flat DataFrame, using the `group` value to indicate which row of the original array the data came from:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (0, 1, 2),
    (1, 1, 5),
    (1, 93, 46),
    (2, 4, 3)], dtype='f8', columns=['group', 'x', 'y'])
print(df)
#    group     x     y
# 0    0.0   1.0   2.0
# 1    1.0   1.0   5.0
# 2    1.0  93.0  46.0
# 3    2.0   4.0   3.0
```

Then the first operation is merely a slice of the `x` and `y` columns:

```
print(df[['x','y']])
#       x     y
# 0   1.0   2.0
# 1   1.0   5.0
# 2  93.0  46.0
# 3   4.0   3.0
```

and the second operation can be done using `groupby/idxmax`:

```
print(df.loc[df.groupby('group')['y'].idxmax(), ['x', 'y']])
#       x     y
# 0   1.0   2.0
# 2  93.0  46.0
# 3   4.0   3.0
```

---

Given the structured NumPy array, `arr`, you're going to have to loop through
the lists at least once to perform any of these operations. So you might as well pay the price once to organize the data in a better data structure, such as a Pandas DataFrame.

Here is one way you could convert `arr` to `df`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([([1.     ], [2.     ]),
                ([1., 93.], [5., 46.]),
                ([4.     ], [3.     ])],
               dtype=[('x','O'), ('y', 'O')])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df = (pd.concat({col: df[col].apply(pd.Series).stack() for col in df}, axis=1)
      .reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)
```

yields

```
      x     y
0   1.0   2.0
1   1.0   5.0
2  93.0  46.0
3   4.0   3.0
```

Comment: Nice way, thanks! The problem is that I get the data from outside and they're in the format I described in OP, which is a pain...